# AttributeError: module 'graphing' has no attribute 'histogram'

Tags: machine-learning, python, matplotlib

I want to make a histogram plot, after importing the library called graphing it gives me an error even when it has been installed.

```
import graphing

graphing.histogram(dataset, label_x='Pclass', label_y='Survived', histfunc='avg', include_boxplot=True)
```

And here's the error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15336\3609384830.py in <module>
      1 import graphing
      2 
----> 3 graphing.histogram(dataset, label_x='Pclass', label_y='Survived', histfunc='avg', include_boxplot=True)

AttributeError: module 'graphing' has no attribute 'histogram'
```

Do you have some advice on how to handle this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that Python has managed to import the `graphing` package, but that the package has no attribute/function called `histogram`.

Some possible explanations are:

- This is the wrong name for the function you want (in matplotlib, which you've tagged, the function is `hist` not `histogram`).
- The function is in a sub-module of graphing, so you need to call `graphing.<submodule>.histogram`.
- You are importing the wrong `graphing` package. You can use variables such as `graphing.__path__` (which tells you where the package has been loaded from) to help work out if this is the problem.